# MSSQL window functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need the set items in order of `dateshipped` but in the middle of a CTE.
I am using a window function to set an order of items (since I cannot use order by).

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [sku] order by [dateshipped] desc) as [rows]
,[sku]
,[dateshipped]
,[priceperunit]
from [Order Details]
```

the problem I am running into is when the `dateshipped` is null a row number is not assigned to that item.

how would I get a row number assigned when `dateshipped` is null?

Comment: This isn't correct. When `dateshipped` is `null` they will be ordered first in the partition. (sorry last as you have `desc` direction). [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29748)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `dateshipped` is `NULL` they will be ordered anyway as if it was the earliest `datetime`, the same as if you use a nullable-column in a normal `ORDER BY`. However, you can use `CASE` first to specify if the nulls come first or last:

```
SELECT Row_number() 
         OVER( 
           partition BY [sku] 
           ORDER BY CASE WHEN dateshipped IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, 
         dateshipped DESC) AS [rows], 
       [sku], 
       [dateshipped], 
       [priceperunit] 
FROM   [order details]
```

Comment: you were correct i made a mistake and the original info was not in that table... once i put it in the problem was fixexd.
Thank you !